# Lync install on XP machines closes Office applications

Tags: windows-xp, lync, outlook-2003

Our company is in the process of deploying Lync to our users. We intend to use GFI LANGuard to deploy the software to client machines. In testing, the installation has gone smooth on both Vista and Win7 systems. But on XP machines, when the install completes, it closes any open MS Office programs. More troubling, is that Outlook is closed, then reopens automatically, but prompts for a new profile to be created. If you cancel this, then reopen Outlook once more, it's fine, it returns to the user's original profile.

So, the issue is that the majority of our PCs run XP. If we push this out with this behavior, users will freak out, and it will just result in desktop visits, thereby negating the advantage of pushing the installer out via LANGuard.

Google searches have not been too helpful. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The installation of Lync requires all Office applications to be closed during installation. What happens after the Lync installation and a reboot? Does everything come up fine after the reboot?

Comment: That hasn't been the case for deploying Lync to Vista and Win7 systems; even with Outlook and Word running, there are no problems. The issue described above only occurs on XP systems.